# Extender controls must be registered using RegisterExtenderControl() before calling RegisterScriptDescriptors()

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am trying to deploy a web application built with Dotnetnuke. There is an DNN Control/ASCX having a MultiView and few AjaxToolkit Controls like AutoComplete, ModalPopup. In Views other (plain) ASCXs are included and some of which have UpdatePanel.

On the developer machine (WinXp / ASP.NET Web Server) there is no error...but when I try to deploy it on server, I get the above error.

Comment: Server is Windows 2003 Sp2 with .NET 3.5 Sp1. AjaxToolkit is not installed on server, instead its DLL is placed in the application' bin folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the latest AjaxToolkit release, but problem remained the same...

It appears that it has something to do with MultiView, the control itself is loading dynamically into DNN. Removing MultiView has resolved the issue.

The production site is running a bit older version of Dotnetnuke, and the developer is using the latest Dotnetnuke. This may be the issue...However we tried disabling SupportsPartialRendering option of DNN and adding ScriptManager ourselves...but it didnt resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Even  I had the same problem while using PopupControlExtender, but the issue was resolved when i removed the "OffsetX" tag from PopupControlExtender

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any declarative statement in the user control or page control in asp.net then paste that following code in to your page.it should work without fail.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        if (this.DesignMode == true)
        {
            this.EnsureChildControls();
        }
        this.Page.RegisterRequiresControlState(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works in VS 2010 and VS  2012 On Page event

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  {
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    ToolkitScriptManager1.RegisterExtenderControl(HoverMenuExtender1, Page);
  }

}
```